# Creating an image from divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I had tried forEach appending to create the image.

I tried to make a display with divs, but it didn't work, Drowning in errors.

I was unable to find any solutions, which is why I'm asking.

Can someone help me? Thank you!

```
let array = [];
let visuals = []

let n = 0;
while(n<100){
    n = n + 1;
    array.push(n);
}
n = 0;
let x;
let y;
let temp;
while(n<100){
    n = n + 1;
    x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    temp = array[x];
    array[x] = array[y];
    array[y] = temp;
}

console.log("Unsorted:")
console.log(array)
console.log("Sorting: ")
let i = 0;
while(i<100){
    i = i + 1;
    n = -1;
    while(n<100-i){
        n = n + 1;
        if(array[n] > array[n+1]){
            temp = array[n];
            array[n] = array[n+1];
            array[n+1] = temp;
        }
    }
console.log(array);
visuals.push(array)
}
i = 0;
visuals.forEach(function(item){
    i = i + 1;
    let newEL = document.createElement("div");
    newEL.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    newEL.style.filter = "brightness(" + item + "%)";
    newEL.style.width = "1px";
    newEL.style.height = "1px";
    document.getElementById("output").appendChild(newEL);
})
```

Comment: Please post your expected results as this is a bit unusual.  Perhaps enhance your question as a functional snippet (there is a button for that) with your HTML and Javascript

Comment: i see no errors, and your code does produce a lot of small 1px divs in a row. Try making them 10px height and width to see them more clearly

Comment: why are you first randomizing the array and then sorting it? You always end up with the same array

Comment: The code is a little strange. For example, what does the first loop with the swapping achieve?

Answer (score 0):

This is a corrected version of your code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #output {
            display: flex;
        }
        .array-element {
            width: 5px;
            height: 50px;
            margin: 2px;
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="output"></div>

    <script>
        let array = [];
        let visuals = [];

        let n = 0;
        while (n < 100) {
            n = n + 1;
            array.push(n);
        }
        n = 0;
        let x;
        let y;
        let temp;
        while (n < 100) {
            n = n + 1;
            x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
            y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
            temp = array[x];
            array[x] = array[y];
            array[y] = temp;
        }

        console.log("Unsorted:");
        console.log(array);
        console.log("Sorting: ");
        let i = 0; // Declare i only once
        while (i < 100) {
            i = i + 1;
            n = -1;
            while (n < 100 - i) {
                n = n + 1;
                if (array[n] > array[n + 1]) {
                    temp = array[n];
                    array[n] = array[n + 1];
                    array[n + 1] = temp;
                    // Push a copy of the array to the visuals array
                    visuals.push([...array]);
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Function to display the visual array
        function displayVisualArray() {
            const output = document.getElementById("output");
            output.innerHTML = ''; // Clear the output

            visuals[i].forEach(function (value) {
                let newEL = document.createElement("div");
                newEL.classList.add("array-element");
                newEL.style.height = value * 5 + "px"; // Adjust the height based on the value
                output.appendChild(newEL);
            });
        }

        // Display the initial unsorted array
        displayVisualArray();

        // Visualize the sorting process
        i = 0; // Use the same 'i' variable
        function visualizeSort() {
            if (i < visuals.length) {
                displayVisualArray();
                i++;
                setTimeout(visualizeSort, 50); // Adjust the delay between each step
            }
        }

        // Start the visualization
        visualizeSort();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```